# How to parse XML element from SOAP response using Jsoup

Tags: java, soap, jsoup

I'm having problem in parsing XML element returned by SOAP because the XML structure is like this :

```
    <a:journey>
    <a:infantprice>0</a:infantprice>
    ...
    </a:journey>
```

I have tried

```
.select("journey")
.select("a:journey")
```

But still not getting the xml value. Is it possible to select the XML segment with that format using Jsoup?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, I got the answer for my question.

I should use :

```
.select("a|journey");
```

According to the documentation :

> ns|tag: find elements by tag in a namespace, e.g. fb|name finds
>    elements

Source : 
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Thanks

Comment: Please *accept* your answer (after 24 h) so others can see it's solved (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)